# Cannot take picture with Canon Rebel XT connected to Pi3 via gphoto2

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, camera, image, computer-vision

When I try to take an automatic picture with my SLR camera (Canon Rebel XT) via the following command in gphoto2:

```
gphoto2 --trigger-capture
```

It returns an error as follow

```
*** Error ***              
Sorry, your camera does not support generic capture
ERROR: Could not trigger capture.
*** Error (-6: 'Unsupported operation') ***       

For debugging messages, please use the --debug option.
Debugging messages may help finding a solution to your problem.
If you intend to send any error or debug messages to the gphoto
developer mailing list <gphoto-devel@lists.sourceforge.net>, please run
gphoto2 as follows:

    env LANG=C gphoto2 --debug --debug-logfile=my-logfile.txt --trigger-capture

Please make sure there is sufficient quoting around the arguments.
```

To resolve that I tried to find (and kill) any other ongoing gphoto2 process, but I couldn't find any:

```
ps -A
```

I also checked if the camera is properly connected and recognized by Pi3 via:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gphoto2 --auto-detect 
Model                          Port                                            
----------------------------------------------------------
Canon EOS 350D                 usb:001,016
```

Another fact that might be helpful to troubleshoot this is that when I connect my LSR to Pi3 it says "busy" on its screen.

Thanks you!

Comment: Can you try out your camera with a normal laptop running Linux? Can you collect a detailed log as the error message describes (with --debug etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names and models of the cameras supported by `gphoto` is listed here:
http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php

Canon Rebel XT is not on the list and therefore I should probably use another camera to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.